# How do I display a message when no results are found in drupal 7 views

Tags: drupal-7

I'm global:php to display data in my views page. In case there is no data's in view that time its showing empty screen. But i want to display "no match forund" instead of empty screen.

Comment: Hello jawahar, are you doing any computations in global:php ?

Comment: Rendering the block is not working in global:php, i also tried may ways still i couldn't figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the 'Views PHP' module enabled in order to use Global:PHP.